# List view in category page on 1 column layout magento

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I set category page to only listing view on 1 column layout in magento? Is that configurable on the admin?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Christophe, Yes but using RWD Theme. But I saw also the configuration via Admin

Comment: I want to do it with theming or admin, I do not care really. Thanks for the help you can give.